# Many "Sources" Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, citing-sources

Why do we have [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) but also [sources-rishonim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-rishonim) and [sources-acharonim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-acharonim)? Should they all be put together, or is there some value in sometimes being able to sort questions by what kind of source is being sought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I support a full merger with [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) (or maybe [sources-mekorot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-mekorot)) being the final version.

Comment: As this seems to be the consensus of the community, I've implemented it.