# the 'sources' tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We have a [sources-mekorot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-mekorot) tag.

1. To the best of my recollection, it's until very recently been used primarily or only for questions that present a statement, *halacha*, or idea and seek only a source for it.
2. In the past few days, however, I've seen it used also for questions that seek both a definitive statement or *halacha* and a source for it. (I've [undone](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/27549/revisions) a few such taggings, in line with the older usage.)

What should we do with this tag? Some possibilities are:

- Use it as in #1 above.
- Use it as in #2 above.
- Don't use it.

Please propose these or other ideas as answers so people may vote them up or down. (Votes on this *question* will be meaningless.)

Please also note [older discussion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/851).

Comment: -1 good question

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/should-we-remove-the-list-tag

Answer (score 4):

I propose we get rid of the tag. Tags are good for search engines (a question tagged [passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover) will be findable when one searches for *Passover* even if the word *Passover* isn't in the question), for browsing (people can browse all Passover-related questions at [the tag page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover) and can 'favorite' or 'ignore' specific tags), and for identification (people can see what a question's about by glancing at its tags). None of these seems applicable to the [sources-mekorot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources-mekorot) tag.

Comment: It reminds me of the homework tag on SO

Comment: Agreed.  I've added it to a few questions since becoming aware of it (for consistency), but I don't really see the value of it.

Comment: So, shall we go ahead and remove it?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, because I and two upvoters think so and no one has expressed a contrary opinion? I dunno.

Comment: @msh210 and whoa, it's on almost a thousand questions.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No matter how many of them there are, you have to just do the right thing and deport, err I mean, remove them from the site!

Comment: @IsaacMoses Now it's 4 votes. And we now know that there are magical powers which can avoid the issue of how ubiquitous it is.